# if function not functioning properly? still picking up 0 and empty textbox

Tags: vba, excel

The if function below should function if i had values other than 0 or empty space... however for some reason it still runs the code even though my value for Util_NumberQC = 0 would you know what the problem is? thank you in advance

```
Private Sub Util_NumberQC_Change()

    Dim Util_Get As Integer
    Dim LastRowQC As Long
    Dim FoundCell As Range


If Util_NumberQC.Value <> 0 Or Util_NumberQC.Value <> "" Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `Util_NumberQC.Value = 0` then it is not an empty string `(= "")` and since you are using an `or operator (||)` it is meeting the condition you set.

Since you say the value is 0 and it shouldn't be executing, I think what you are actually looking for is:

```
If Util_NumberQC.Value <> 0 And Util_NumberQC.Value <> "" Then
```

Which in pseudo English means If (value) is not 0, AND (value) is not an empty string Then do stuff.

Comment: double negatives are just as confusing in code as they are not not in English